Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read
I am getting an error when I try to read a response twice:
I need the response in a form of text assigned to a cosnt, e.g. (api_response.text()) and then I need to pass the api_response.json() to a function:
if (api_response_text == 'true') {
  const api_request = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  }).then(async api_response => {
    const api_response_text = await api_response.text();
    if (api_response.ok) {
      if (onCompleted) {
        onCompleted(await api_response.json());
      }    
    } else {                
      console.log(api_response_text)
    }
  });
}

I tired with clone() like so:
const api_response_clone = await api_response.clone();
and:
console.log(api_response_clone.text());
but then I got [object Promise] as the response text, which is not what I need.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Once you have the text, why not just parse the string as JSON?

Will the api_response_text be already assigned if I do onCompleted(JSON.parse(api_response_text)); instead of onCompleted(await api_response.json());?

It was assigned on the previous line. Why wouldn't it be assigned?

Change the last call to console.log(await api_response_clone.text());

you don't need to await the clone() method. It returns a Reponse, not a Promise.

Do you really need the text if the response is OK? It looks like you only use the JSON in that case. So call api_response.text() in the else block.

Move the call to text() to the else block, since that's the only place where you need the raw text.
Mixing await and .then() also makes your code more confusing than necessary. Stick to await when you can.
if (api_response_text == 'true') {
  const api_response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  });
  if (api_response.ok) {
    if (onCompleted) {
      onCompleted(await api_response.json());
    }
  } else {
    console.log(await api_response.text());
  }
}

